# NullPointerException while using Android's mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have two button and it will play a sound to notify about right choice, or wrong one. 
This is how I do it:

```
MediaPlayer playError = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.error);
playError.start();
```

Same with correct sound. It works fine most of the time, but when I click it many times, at random times I get this error:

Basically it says line **playError.start();** gives me **NullPointerException** (only sometimes)

```
07-21 23:05:32.767: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1287): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource, -17
07-21 23:05:32.767: ERROR/MediaPlayer(14449): error (1, -17)
07-21 23:05:32.767: ERROR/MediaPlayer(14449): MEDIA_ERROR(mPrepareSync) signal application thread
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at com.quiz.QuizActivity.falseAnswerPoints(QuizActivity.java:148)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at com.quiz.QuizActivity$5.onClick(QuizActivity.java:86)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-21 23:05:32.777: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit:**

Line is 148: playError.start();

And falseAnswerPoints() is:

```
public void falseAnswerPoints() {
    MediaPlayer playError = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.error);
    playError.start();
}
```

Same is correctAnswerPoints, but with different sound. That's about it. Sometimes it gives NullPointerException with one, sometimes with another...

**Answer:**

```
MediaPlayer playSuccess = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.success);
playSuccess.start();
playSuccess.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer playSuccess) {
        playSuccess.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code please?

Comment: Would you post the method falseAnswerPoints() of QuizActivity.java, and show us which line is the 148 ?

Comment: @Badr_Hari Thx! I've responded below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `MediaPlayer` cannot be created, the `create()` method returning a `null` pointer. The [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) says this happens when the creation fails, with no further details.

You said this happens when you click several times in a row on the button that leads this method to be called. This is probably due to a non reentrancy issue.

You should try to surround the `MediaPlayer` creation and usage by a flag that would prevent reentrancy:

```
public void falseAnswerPoints() {
    if (!mPlayingSound) {
        mPlayingSound = true;

        MediaPlayer playError = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.error);
        playError.start();
    }
}
```

`mPlayingSound` being a `private boolean` member initialized to `false` and that you would reset to `false` once the `MediaPlayer` would have finished playing (using `public void setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)` should be fine, although I am not sure whether it is called in case of abnormal or anticipated termination of the play).

**EDIT**:
There is a NullPointerException so there is a stack trace.
To capture the stack trace, in debug only (the code below is not suitable for release), you can do as follows:

```
public void falseAnswerPoints() {
    try {
        MediaPlayer playError = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.error);
        playError.start();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Set a breakpoint there to inspect the state of your app
        // Then rethrow the exception to have it logged, and why not
        // log extra info.
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did something like this, but this doesnt seem to work. I only get an error when I debug the app with my phone. I have currently only one Android phone to test with. With an emulator I am not able to reproduce the error...

Comment: In that case, I suggest setting a conditional breakpoint that would act when playError is null. Did you manage to come to a scenario that makes the bug 100% reproduceable (such as "clicking 10 times in a row", or stng like this)?

Comment: Yes, the bug is reproduceable by clicking things in row. It doesnt matter how fast... but usually around 10 clicks. It's not always the same number. Now I was able to get same error with emulator also. With emulator it also gives me errors like:
07-21 20:39:24.770: ERROR/AudioService(67): Media server died.
07-21 20:39:28.890: ERROR/AudioService(67): Media server started.

I also tried try catch to find an excpetion, but it doesnt give me anything... but thanks for thinking with my about my problem, Shlubu ☺

Comment: You are welcome! This kind of issue is annoying. As there is a NullPointerEXception there is a stack trace. I've edited my answer above to suggest a way to capture it and to inspect the state of the app at the same time.

Comment: Thank you again, Shlublu, thx to your ideas I got it working... I am using MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener to realese the audio and this seems to do the trick. I added the code to my question...

Comment: Yipii \o/ Good news ! Too bad for the NPE. Maybe I should have suggested Exception instead of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid all answers here are wrong. I encountered this issue, albeit more than a year later, but after some research found the answer. It's in two parts.

> 1. Best to start the mediaplayer AFTER the declaration of the onCompleteListener. This insures that the mediaplayer has a full list
>      of instructions declared before it even start playing.
> 2. Use a statically declared object called an AtomicBoolean. This insures that there is only one boolean parameter, and that the process
>      is locked until it finishes the process. This is the only way to
>      insure a process is thread safe.

Hope you found this useful (all future programmers that encounter this problem) ;-)

Answer (score -3):

To solve your problem you can try to write a permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

in manifest