# Global MediaPlayer declaration not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, global-variables, android-mediaplayer

Whenever i want to declare a local Mediaplayer it just crashes. I have declared in a local method and the song plays perfectly fine. But when i want to declare it globally it does not work.

```
package com.example.simplerecipes;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {


    MediaPlayer ColdplaySong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay );
        ColdplaySong.start();

        Thread Timer = new Thread (){

            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openMainMenu = new Intent("com.example.simplerecipes.MainActivty");
                    startActivity(openMainMenu);
                }

            }

        };
        Timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ColdplaySong.release();
        finish();
    }

}
```

here are the errors in the LogCat

```
09-13 08:12:30.004: D/AndroidRuntime(825): Shutting down VM
09-13 08:12:30.004: W/dalvikvm(825): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplerecipes/com.example.simplerecipes.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at com.example.simplerecipes.About.onCreate(About.java:16)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-13 08:12:30.014: E/AndroidRuntime(825):     ... 11 more       
09-13 08:12:33.154: I/Process(825): Sending signal. PID: 825 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Change MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay ); to ColdplaySong.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay );

Comment: Check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782109/nullpointerexception-while-using-androids-mediaplayer

Comment: You should accept laalto's answer. Also, you should probably stop liking Coldplay ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
MediaPlayer ColdplaySong;
```

This declares a variable but does not initialize it (by default, the object reference will be null).

```
MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay );
```

This creates a `MediaPlayer` instance but does not store the reference anywhere.

```
ColdplaySong.start();
```

This calls a method on a null object, causing NullPointerException.

What you probably want is:

```
ColdplaySong = MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay );
ColdplaySong.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the MediaPlayer object using final keyword .

```
package com.example.simplerecipes;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {


  final MediaPlayer ColdplaySong =MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.coldplay );
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.about);

      ColdplaySong.start();

      Thread Timer = new Thread (){

          public void run(){
              try{
                  sleep(5000);
              }catch (InterruptedException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }finally{
                  Intent openMainMenu = new Intent("com.example.simplerecipes.MainActivty");
                  startActivity(openMainMenu);
              }

          }

      };
      Timer.start();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPause();
      ColdplaySong.release();
      finish();
  }

}
```